# In nHibernate, how can I change the database connection (different db) dynamically?

Tags: nhibernate

If I want to do vertical partitioning of my db, how could I change the database connection dynamically on a per query basis?

i.e. userID > 100000 use db1, otherwise use db0.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491139/how-do-you-change-nhibernates-connection-string-per-http-request).